# Cannot get WCF resful service to use https/ssl

Tags: web-services, wcf, azure, wcf-rest

I'm aware that there has been answers to this question in the past, but after going through many of them I'm still having a problem so I'm hoping someone could look at this configuration and tell me where it's going wrong...

Here's the config for the self hosted rest WCF service I'm deploying:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>

        <appSettings>
            <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
        </appSettings>
        <system.web>
            <customErrors mode="Off"/>    
            <compilation debug="true" />
        </system.web>

        <system.serviceModel>
            <services>
                <service name="SampleService.SampleService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" >
                    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpTransportSecurity" behaviorConfiguration="web" contract="SampleService.ISampleService"/>
                    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
                </service>
            </services>
            <bindings>
                <webHttpBinding>
                    <binding name="webHttpTransportSecurity">
                        <security mode="Transport" >
                            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" />
                        </security>
                    </binding>
                </webHttpBinding>
            </bindings>   
            <behaviors>
                <endpointBehaviors>
                    <behavior name="web">
                        <webHttp />
                    </behavior>
                </endpointBehaviors>
                <serviceBehaviors>
                    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
                        <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="false"/>
                        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                    </behavior>
                </serviceBehaviors>
            </behaviors>
            <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
        </system.serviceModel>
    </configuration>
```

The error on the server is indicating that the service wants to use http and not https and I can't for the life of me figure out what is wrong with the configuration. I've gone over it for the better part of the day. It's a relatively trivial little service.

Comment: Why did you set `clientCredentialType` and `proxyCredentialType` to `"None" on the `<transport>` element?   Doesn't that defeat the purpose?

Comment: None Specifies anonymous authentication.      I don't want to have the user prompted for user/password.

Answer (score 1):

The service endpoint addresses in your service element are *relative*, meaning that that they are relative to the *base address* of your service. By default, the base address uses the **http** scheme, which is what your service is using.
So, if your base address is http://localhost/myservice, then your two endpoints will be http://localhost/myservice and http://localhost/myservice/mex.

You can make your endpoint addresses *absolute* by including the scheme (https) and full Uri. For example, "https://localhost/myservice" and "https://localhost/myservice/mex" instead of "" and "mex" like you have now.

Or, you can just add a base address to your service that uses the **https** scheme like this.

```
<host>
  <baseAddresses>
    <add baseAddress="https://localhost/myservice"/>
  </baseAddresses>
</host>
```

This assumes that you've taken care of registering your SSL certificate to support transport security.  If you haven't, then you will will need to do that too.

As a side note, I would suggest using **ASP.NET Web API** for RESTful web services instead of WCF.  [Here is a brief intro](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) to get you started if you're not familiar with it.

Comment: Hey Rick, I too would prefer to use Web API, unfortunately the project I'm working on had decided to use WCF, I'm sorta stuck with it.

Comment: So yes, I do have the ssl configured and the hosting site itself (cloud service) is secure. It's just when I attempt to access the service on the site is where I have this problem.

Comment: This is in a web role?

Comment: Indeed it is in  a web role. sorry for not providing the full picture in the description.

Comment: Did you configure the endpoint on the cloud service to use SSL?  I show how to do this for traditional WCF endpoints (not webHttp) here. http://rickrainey.com/2013/09/18/securing-a-wcf-service-in-an-azure-web-role-with-http-tcp-endpoints-2/  But, I believe the configuration on the cloud service will be the same.

Comment: Yes, the cloud service has been configured with ssl and is running fine... I use this   https://devkkrasnowskyservices.cloudapp.net/   it works fine... but trying to access the service:  https://devkkrasnowskyservices.cloudapp.net/sampleservice.svc    does this.

Answer (score 0):

well this unfortunately was yet one more reminder that I shouldn't try to piece together prototype code from a third party unless I'm very sure on how it's setup. Would have been better off starting from scratch (which I eventually did). As it turned out, how I configured this was perfectly valid but the azure service packaging and deployment process in the solution was malformed.

Sorry for the wasted bandwidth and thanks for all who attempted to help me out.